# how to show multiple info window of GMS mapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gmsmapview

I want to add multiple info windows to appear at the same time with out tapping on the marker .
How to implement this ?

Here is my code to add multiple markers and adding a infoWindow?

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonDataDict.count; i ++) {
        NSDictionary *newDict = [jsonDataDict objectAtIndex:i ];

        double latitude = [[newDict valueForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue];
        double longitute = [[newDict valueForKey:@"lng"]doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitute);
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
        nameOfPlace = [newDict valueForKey:@"name"];
       // distanceOfPlace = [newDict valueForKey:@"distance"];
        marker.icon = [self image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinPopoye.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(75.0f, 60.0f)];
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
        marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(1.1, 0.70);
        marker.map = self.mapView;

      [self.mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];

      //[self mapView:self.mapView markerInfoWindow:marker];


    }
}

     - (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
       {
    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 25)];
    customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:71.0/255.0 green:65.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:0.8];
    customView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    customView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 10)];
    nameLabel.text = nameOfPlace;
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
    [customView addSubview:nameLabel];

    distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 12, 60, 10)];
    distanceLabel.text = distanceOfPlace;
    distanceLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    distanceLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    distanceLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
    [customView addSubview:distanceLabel];

    return customView;
}
```

Comment: As per google docs, info window is called when a marker is about to become selected

Comment: It looks like the info windows in Objective-C cannot be directly controlled except the contents. See [Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#info_windows). It is also explicitly said that "Only one info window is displayed at a time." so I guess there can't be multiple windows for ios.

Comment: @gerardnimo - So how can i show different labels for every marker ?